# What is the translation of “living inheritance" in French?

Tags: traduction, finance

I [read](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/the-joys-and-drawbacks-of-a-living-inheritance-11634922595):

> Many of my older clients ask me, “How much can I gift to my family today, while I am living?” This is a strategy known as a **living inheritance**, and it can be a very powerful tool — as long as you carefully consider and prioritize protecting your own financial security.

What's the translation of "living inheritance" in French?

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=living%20inheritance&op=translate) and linguee didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il s'agit probablement d'une [*donation entre vifs*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8977114) (si on parle bien d'un [*inter vivos gift*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=INTER%20VIVOS%20DONATION&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)). Il pourrait s'agir d'une formulation moins technique (ou en finance) avec une locution comme *donation/transfert* (plus général)/*donner* (voire *léguer*) *de son [vivant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivant)*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130997/discussion-on-answer-by-yoye-doncques-what-is-the-translation-of-living-inher).

Comment: The answer could be better. Because you're talking about a _strategy known as_ you can't really use _donation entre vifs_ in this very context, because that's just a thing at law, and the article is about wealth management, and I was looking for a word to describe it and I found it: _customer facing_. It's the world of planning and insurance and such, and packages and products and so on. In context this was simply contrasting inheritance at death with a living one, it is casual wording. Maybe _chattels_ is a good comparison, I mean you wouldn't find it in such an article, you would find...

Comment: ...a reference to objects of lesser value such as furniture and the like. Anyways. my point is what in the context of naming the strategy, insofar as my answer is concerned, you have to go, instead of _known as_ with sth. like _consisting in_ i.e. _qui consiste à_ + _donner/faire des donations/avantager_ etc. _de son vivant_ (plutôt qu'à son décès vraiment). So yeah, the answer could be improved or another answer can reframe it along those lines. Thanks. @Franck

Answer (score 0):

The legal procedure that corresponds to "living inheritance" must be "*Donation en avance de part successorale*".

> [www.notaires.fr Le site officiel des notaires de France](https://www.notaires.fr/fr/donation-succession/donation/succession-les-r%C3%A8gles-%C3%A0-conna%C3%AEtre-pour-faire-une-donation)
>
> Succession : les règles à connaître pour faire une donation
>
> Donner à un héritier : simple avance sur succession ou avantage ?
>
> Une donation faite à un héritier réservataire (enfant(s) ou à défaut le conjoint) peut être en avance de part successorale ou hors part successorale. Une donation faite à un héritier non réservataire ou à un étranger à la succession sera imputée sur la quotité disponible (la réserve héréditaire revenant aux héritiers réservataires).
>
> **Donation en avance de part successorale**
>
> Une donation en avancement de part successorale consiste pour un donateur à attribuer à un héritier réservataire, tout ou partie de sa part d' héritage en avance. Il n’est ainsi pas porté atteinte à l’égalité avec les autres héritiers.
>
> Sauf indication contraire de la part du donateur, toute donation est présumée être faite en avance de part successorale.

Comment: https://www.justice.gc.ca/fra/pr-rp/sjc-csj/harmonization/siroi/don-gift3.html

Comment: @Lambie Qui parle d'héritage là-dedans ? Qu'est-ce que vous trouvez de plus spécifique ?

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques La question ne parle pas d'héritage donc et elle concerne des frères et des sœurs seulement ? … ah oui … je vois.

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques Hors-sujet !

Comment: Si on traduit de l'anglais en français le terme living inheritance, le français n'est pas donation en avance de avance de part successorale. Pourquoi? Parce que le régime de la common law pour le texte en anglais n'est pas un régime de forced heirship comme il y a en France. Cette traduction va bien au-delà de l'idée en angalis.  Cela n'existe pas en anglais  pour le terme living inheritance.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est-ce que vous faites de la référence donnée par le PO ? on y trouve ceci : « a living inheritance can help your children and grandchildren surmount these challenges ». Une living inheritance » est une procédure conçue pour donner l'héritage ou une partie, avant la mort, et aux héritiers tels que les enfants. C'est bien la même chose que « donation en avance de part successorale ». Il n'y a aucun doute. Lisez les références et produisez les contradictions, s'il y en a.

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques Bla !

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques Bla !

Comment: LPH: Tu as un problème de méthodologie en traduction. Le système de réserve héréditaire en France (forced heirship en anglais) n'est pas de mise ici.

Comment: @Lambie  Again, blah !

Comment: It is a translation error of " living inheritance": the translation is donation entre-vifs

Answer (score -1):

Il me semble qu'en français on appelle ça l'[avance sur héritage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avance_sur_h%C3%A9ritage).

La question est complexe car elle relève du droit plus que de la linguistique. En France, la donation à des héritiers est encadrée, les dons qui sont faits à des héritiers doivent être comptés dans l'héritage et déclarés.

Comment: No, this is wrong. France has forced heirship but that does not mean you can't translate the idea. Et puisque on traduit un texte à partir de l' anglais (donc un texte rédigé en régime de common law), le système en France ne s'applique pas. L'idée existe en français. donation entre vifs. All inter vivos gifts are paid out prior to estate settlement.